# Счетчик посетителей на куках

Tags: php

Идея такая: пользователь заходит на сайт и ему дается оригинальная кука, когда он просматривает новость, к просмотрам добавляется + 1, если уже есть кука, то не обновлять счетчик просмотров. Вот подскажите, как такое реализовать? На сессиях у меня получилось, а на куках нет.

Comment: А как "печенька" должна влиять на счетчик? Если я правильно понял, то если пользователь не залогинился, то и счетчик накручивать не надо. Если не так, то поправьте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//записали
setcookie('some_var', 1);    
//прочитали
echo $_COOKIE['some_var'];
```

**Добавлено из комментария**.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['view_' . $id])){
        mysql_query ("UPDATE news SET view= view + 1 WHERE id='".$id."'",$db); 
        setcookie('view_' . $id, 1);
    }
```

Только учтите, размер кук ~4кб.

Comment: вы что вообще не туда смотрите такое я видел и в мануалках

Comment: Тогда не вижу сложности переделать сессии на куки.

Comment: у меня не получается

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Comment: спс вот это работает гуд!

Answer (score 0):

это не важно вот пример на ссеиях вы поймете что я имею ввиду

```
<?php session_start(); 
if(!isset($_SESSION['view'][$id])){
mysql_query ("UPDATE news SET view= view + 1 WHERE id='".$id."'",$db); 
$_SESSION['view'][$id] = $id;
?>
```

Comment: Ну так а в чем тогда проблема, по большому счету вам надо `$_SESSION['view'][$id]` поменять на `$_COOKIE['view'] == $id`

Comment: псс но это не работает